# Inner models and strongly compact cardinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-models

The following question is motivated by a result of Magidor that it is consistent that the least strongly compact cardinal is the least measurable cardinal.

> **Question.** Assume $\kappa$ is a strongly compact cardinal. Is there an inner model $M$ of the universe such that  $M \models$``$\kappa$
>   is  strongly compact and the set of measurable cardinals below $\kappa$
>   is unbounded in $\kappa$'' $?$

Comment: I don't know enough about inner model theory, but are there any ad hoc inner models for very large cardinals? I mean, are there even results of this type known?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, there are some arguments producing inner models of very large cardinals. See for example my paper with Apter and Gitman: http://jdh.hamkins.org/innermodelswithlargecardinals/.  For example, if there is a supercompact cardinal, then there is an inner model with an indestructible supercompact cardinal, and another inner model with a supercompact cardinal at which the GCH fails. Our methods don't seem, however, to answer the current question.

Comment: Mohammad, it is a nice question.  I don't think we know even how to get at least one measurable cardinal below the strongly compact cardinal in an inner model, let alone unboundedly many.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let me add more such results other those mentioned by Prof. Hamkins. One is the work of Foreman on inner models for Huge cardinals. See [Smoke and mirrors: combinatorial properties of small cardinals equiconsistent with huge cardinals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809001406)

Comment: - and [Chang's conjecture, generic elementary embeddings and inner models for huge cardinals](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9956662&fileId=S1079898615000190). I may also mention the worn of Neeman and Steel ``[Equiconsistencies at subcompact cardinals](https://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/equiconsistencies.subcompacts.pdf)''.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, it seems even this weaker version is not known.